# Load Previously Selected from DB into p:selectcheckBoxMenu in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.2.8 and primefaces 6.0, and i have a selectCheckBoxMenu.

Values selected will be persisted into DB. During edit operation i need to load previously selected value.

Here is my selectCheckBoxMenu

```
 <p:outputLabel for="ressource" value="Ressource"/>
                    <h:panelGroup >         
                     <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="ressource" label="Ressource" value="#{affectationBean.selectedRessource}"  multiple="true">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{affectationBean.ressources}" var="r" itemLabel="#{r.nom}" itemValue="r.idt_ressource" />
                        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                     </h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save"  actionListener="#{affectationBean.save}" />
```

On loading from db i am filling mybean.selectedRessource with DB values  but in UI its not showing as selected

Comment: So it works if you do all this from a static array without any DB access??

Comment: @Kukeltje. Just tried static with strings and its working but from DB its not working.

Comment: Kukeltje didn't mean that you should replace "ressources" by strings. Kukeltje just meant that you should replace the database by a static array/list/map.